# How to upload a file to nexus using ansible modules?

Tags: curl, ansible, nexus

Are we able to use URI module of ansible to upload a file to nexus rather than using
curl --upload-file as a shell task ?

Answer (score 1):

Since ansible 2.7, [`uri`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html) module has a `src` parameter that should do the trick.

So something like this as a task (to adapt/complete with the behavior of the Nexus API):

```yaml
- name: Push jar to nexus
  uri:
    url: "{{ nexus_url }}/nexus/content/repositories/{{ path_repository }}/{{ artifact_name }}"
    method: PUT
    src: "{{ local_file_path }}"
    user: "{{ user }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    #headers:
    #  Content-Type: application/octet-stream  # To avoid automatic 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    status_code:
      - 201
```

Comment: i have tried it   url: "{{ nexus_url }}/{{repository_path }} " and it is not working  Status code was 403

Comment: Try adding `force_basic_auth: yes`

Comment: this is the curl query: curl -v -u user:password --upload-file file.json nexus_url/nexus/content/repositories/path_repository

Comment: To get the file it's working but to upload it, it is not

Comment: Looks like it should be a `PUT`, not a `POST`

Comment: Sadly the ansible task should be equivalent to the curl command. Next step would be to [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/debugging.html#debugging-modules) uri module to find what's wrong in the request it does. Or you could set a local proxy (or simple server) to trace the HTTP call it does and compare to what it should do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220856/discussion-between-slim-azaiz-and-zigarn).

Comment: Found that as soon as there is a body, the 'content-type' header is set to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', may be better by forcing 'application/octet-stream'?

Comment: ('Content-Type' is automatically set if absent and there is data in [python `urllib.request`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4a97b1517a6b5ff22e2984b677a680b07ff0ce11/Lib/urllib/request.py#L1268))

Comment: Thanks for your reactivity but it is the same error message

Comment: Just tested with a local nexus3 server. Found that you need to set the full URL with filename (e.g. `url: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/org/foo/1.0/foo-1.0.jar`) for it to work (unlike with cURL). Then Content-Type trick seems not necessary.

Comment: Yes, it's working on a nexus3 server.
If you can, try to get the logs of Nexus.